# jQuery plugin rotate not working only with ie8

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-8

I'm using the `jquery rotate` plugin to rotate the text that is on the left `#left-menu` 90dg.

The plugin is working fine with all browsers except for IE8. I just don't understand why it doesn't loads.

This is what I get with chrome:

[image]

And this is what is shown with IE8:
[image]

And i'm using this to rotate the text:

```
$('#left-menu').rotate(90);
```

It seems IE8 is not loading the plugin, any ideas why?

jQuery rotate has support up to IE6. Plugin site [here](https://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/)

Comment: IE8 dosent have transform syntax ref: http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d

Comment: Yeah I know that, that's why i'm using the plugin which makes the rotation even for ie6: https://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/

Comment: Check whether your plugin script is after jquery as mentioned in the documentation

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is in the documentation for jQueryRotate.

> I try rotate div element and it works everywhere but not in IE.
>   This plugin was mainly created to rotate images (img) elements ONLY. However it uses CSS attributes in modern browsers that will also work for div elements. That's why it works in other browsers but not IE. If you really need to rotate div you can take a look at experimental version of jQueryRotate 3. You can find it download section.